# Find Expectation of Random variable $\mathbb{E}^*(Y)$

Tags: probability

Consider the measurable space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and the random variables $X$ and $Y$ by $X(\omega)=2I_{(-\infty,0]}(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)=\omega$. Define the measures $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{P}^*$ as

$\mathbb{P}:=0.3\delta_0+0.5\delta_1+0.2\delta_{-1},\quad \frac{d\mathbb{P}^*}{d\mathbb{P}}:=X.$

Find $\mathbb{E}^*(Y)$ :

My solution is as follows:
$\mathbb{P}^{*}=\mathbb{P} * X=2 * 0.3 \delta_{0}=0.6 \delta_{0}$

$\mathbb{E}^{*}(Y)=\sum_{\omega} Y(\omega) * P^{*}(\omega)=Y(0) * 0.6=0$
Is that correct

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\mathbb{P}^*(\omega) & = 2.\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,0]}(\omega) . \left[0.3\delta_0(\omega) + 0.5\delta_1(\omega) + 0.2\delta_{-1}(\omega)\right]\\
& = 0.6\delta_0(\omega) + 0.4\delta_{-1}(\omega)
\end{alignat*}
so
$$
\mathbb{E}^*[Y] = 0\times 0.6 \;+\; (-1)\times 0.4,
$$
and finally $\mathbb{E}^*[Y] = -0.4$.